# How to make Horizontal Line start from the right of div element?

Tags: html, css

```css
CSS: ul {
  list-style: cjk-ideographic;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

li {
  color: #cd8252;
}

ul li p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: none;
}

ul li span.list-ability {
  font-family: 'Centrale-Sans-Medium';
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.list-left {
  width: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

.list-left ul {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.h-line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  border: 2px solid #f1dccf;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-left">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="list-ability">Friendliness</span><div class="h-line"></div><br>
      <p class="list-desc">Be able to be friends with everyone</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="list-ability">Dominance</span><div class="h-line"></div><br/>
      <p class="list-desc">You do not hesitate to impress your own others on others and take charge of situations when required. You may come across as dominant or controlling to others, and appear dismissive of others' views.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="list-ability">Adventuresome</span><div class="h-line"></div><br>
      <p class="list-desc">You prefer routine and staying with familiar roles within your comfort zone. You may nd it di cult to adapt to change and may choose to forgo new experience and opportunities to learn.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The code here would show a list with a horizontal line right after the list label So in this list, I would like the line to start from the right of the  element it is in. Is it possible? If so, what do I need to do?

Comment: but it's already on the right, no?

Comment: yeah, actually it follows after the spanned text since I put display:inline-block, I just put padding to make a space between text and horizontal line. but not starting on the right side of div.

Comment: @MarvinTordillos please review my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want, modified some html and exploited css to reach the goal.

```css
.list-ability {
    position: relative;
}

.list-ability span {
    background-color: white;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.list-ability:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.5em;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-left">
  <ul>
    <li><div class="list-ability"> <span>Friendliness</span></div><div class="h-line"></div><br>
      <p class="list-desc">Be able to be friends with everyone</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div class="list-ability"><span>Dominance</span></div><br/>
      <p class="list-desc">You do not hesitate to impress your own others on others and take charge of situations when required. You may come across as dominant or controlling to others, and appear dismissive of others' views.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div class="list-ability"><span>Adventuresome</span></div><br>
      <p class="list-desc">You prefer routine and staying with familiar roles within your comfort zone. You may nd it di cult to adapt to change and may choose to forgo new experience and opportunities to learn.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this the best answer for me, this is exactly what I was trying to do. Many thanks.

Comment: @MarvinTordillos can you please mark it as the correct answer as this is the required answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we create horizontal line, And i have made it to start from right

```
<div>Somthing</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
 div{
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
div:before{
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 3px solid black;
   width: 40%;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
</style>
```

Comment: I would try this on my end, also.